# Java - Parsing CSV into ArrayList (Need to recognize line breaks)

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

Preface: This is for an assignment in one of my classes.

I need to parse through a CSV file and add each string to an ArrayList so I can interact with each string individually with pre-coded functions.

My problem is that the final string in each line (which doesn't end with a comma) is combined with the first string in the next line and recognized as being at the same index in the ArrayList. I need to learn how to either add a line break or do something else that will stop my loop at the end of each line and read the next line separately. Perhaps there is a built-in method in the scanner class that I'm unaware of that does this for me? Help is appreciated!

Here is the information in the CSV file:

```
Fname,Lname,CompanyName,Balance,InterestRate,AccountInception
Sally,Sellers,Seashells Down By The Seashore,100.36,3,7/16/2002
Michael,Jordan,Jordan Inc.,1000000000,3,6/12/1998
Ignatio,Freely,Penultimate Designs,2300.76,2.4,3/13/1991
```

Here is my code so far

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InterestCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("smalltestdata-sallysellers.csv"));

        // Chomp off at each new line, then add to array or arraylist
        scanner.useDelimiter("\n");

        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {

            // Grab data between commas to add to ArrayList
            scanner.useDelimiter(",");
            // Add grabbed data to ArrayList
            data.add(scanner.next());

        }

        System.out.println(data.get(10));

        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

And here is the output

```
7/16/2002
Michael
```

Comment: If you can, use a dedicated library like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) as an example...

Comment: use `\n` or `\r` or a combination of both in your delimiter list.

Comment: I would use the [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) parser project.

Comment: I tried adding the newline and carriage return escape sequences and it worked! thank you, @Mohammad

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you just need to do...

```
String s[] = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
Collections.addAll(data, s);
```

Comment: That seemed logical, but then my output was:
Seashells Down By The Seashore

That code was adding a comma after each first element in a new line, essentially adding another piece of data to the line.

Comment: @Jared: Sorry, I'm not following what you're saying. Can you give me sample of the input? I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work for the input sample you gave in the post.

Comment: @Jared: is it possible you haven't altered your code the correct way to accommodate this change?